# Show that there are no integers that solve equation

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I want to show that there are no integers $x, y$ that solve the following equation:

$$
15x-9y=100 
$$

My solution would be:

$$
3\cdot5\cdot x-3\cdot3\cdot y = 100 \\
3\cdot(5x-3y) = 100 \\
5x-3y = \frac{100}{3}
$$

Which means that $x$ and $y$ can't be integers. Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, it is perfectly ok.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, this is correct.

A slightly shorter argument would be that 3 is a divisor of the LHS because $15x-9y=3(5x-3y)$ and it is clearly not a divisor of the RHS.

Comment: That's basically the same thing he's saying, though, just in more concise terms